# UI Kitten: can't find variable index (BottomNavigation)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

Actually i'm trying to use BottomNavigation from [UI Kitty](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/bottomnavigation/overview#bottomnavigation) but when i'm trying to swap from one navigation tab to another the app crash with the following error:

> can't find variable index

Here is the code from BottomNavigation where i use index

```
import React from 'react';
import { BottomNavigation, BottomNavigationTab } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import Dashboard from '../navigation/Dashboard';
import Settings from '../navigation/Settings';

export const BottomNavigationShowcase = (props) => {


 const onTabSelect = (selectedIndex) => {
   const { [index] : selectedRoute } = props.navigation.state.routes; // INDEX IS USED HERE
   props.navigation.navigate(selectedRoute.routeName);
 };

 return (
   <BottomNavigation
     selectedIndex={props.navigation.state.index}
     onSelect={onTabSelect}>
     <BottomNavigationTab title='Dashboard' />
     <BottomNavigationTab title='Settings' />
   </BottomNavigation>
  );
}

export const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Dashboard: Dashboard,
  Settings: Settings,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
  tabBarComponent: BottomNavigationShowcase,
});

export default createAppContainer(BottomTabNavigator)
```

And here is App.JS

```
import NavigationContainer from './components/BottomNavigation';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {

  return (
    <ApplicationProvider mapping={mapping} theme={lightTheme}>
    <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
    <Header/>
    <NavigationContainer/>
    </ApplicationProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a problem in `const { [index] : selectedRoute } = props.navigation.state.routes; // INDEX IS USED HERE`
which is not the right way to read an object. 
It seems like you want to read the routes from the props. Why not do something like

```
 const routes = props.navigation.state.routes;
 const selectedRoute = routes[selectedIndex];
 props.navigation.navigate(selectedRoute.routeName);
```

This should fix the app from crashing due to not finding `index`

Comment: that was it, thank you (i'd accept the bounty in 22h)

Comment: you're welcome! im new so not sure how bounty works? once you accept i get the points?

Comment: yes but i can award you only after 24h the bounty has started